# SQL string not line breaking in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have this string in some sql:

```
FT_TBL.Title  + CHAR(13) + 'Job:' + str(FT_TBL.JobName) as Title
```

Now the Title is parsed as a boundfield in a c# gridview, the first row puts "Job" on the next line, but after that its random, some lines are next line some aren't! Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW you shouldn't do your HTML formatting in SQL. Return two data fields and format your grid accordingly.

Comment: that makes sense , but how do you format 2 boundfields into one?

Comment: I would use a template field and lay out accordingly. http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=58

Comment: thanks, this is an alternative, but for now, setting htmlencode worked easier for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I break the a BoundField's HeaderText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310121/how-do-i-break-the-a-boundfields-headertext)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of **char(13)** use **<br />** for line breaks in HTML.

**Note :** Do not forget to add HtmlEncode="false" to your columns that show HTML content :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: This is exaclty it - unless you flag the column as 'nowrap' HTML will wrap w/o the linebreak

Comment: <br /> doesnt seem to work as it just adds <br />  to the text now and doesnt parse it as html in the boundfield :(

Comment: HtmlEncode="false" is not recommended due to potential XSS attacks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Try combining carriage return with line feed:

```
FT_TBL.Title  + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'Job:' + str(FT_TBL.JobName) as Title
```