# How to insert line break in a cell of a grid view?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to know how to put a line break in a cell of a grid view.
Right now, I put

```
1
1
1
```

However, this renders as

```
1 1 1
```

How do I fix the line breaks so that each digit is displayed on its own row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I break the a BoundField's HeaderText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310121/how-do-i-break-the-a-boundfields-headertext)

Answer (score 11):

Add `HtmlEncode="False"`  to `asp:BoundField`
and in the text, should have `< br/>` for line breaks as:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

Comment: This is what I needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the `<br/>` tag to put a line break in your html.

You can use `String.Replace(new char[] { '\n' }, "<br>")` to get the values with line-breaks replaced with `<br/>` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In the `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` you can put:

```
e.Row.Cells[2].Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

For whatever column you're updating. My example is for the third column `(e.Row.Cells[2])`.

Answer (score -1):

in gridview's rowdatabound event, you can check the cell's value's count of digit, and if that value is bigger than 1, you can add html tag `<br />` between them.

but this won't make the digits show in another row, it will still be the same row, just larger (cause it will be for example 3 lines if the value is 111)

Comment: i have multiple names like shakti singh shweeta agarwal then in one cell shakti singh

Comment: i have multiple names in a row i want each name should be displayed in separate row eg in my data sorce i have multiple names in a column's row i want when data bind to gridview each name must be displayed in separate row.

Comment: i would suggest to you 1)if you can, change your "select" query for your datasource 2) create a table at code behind, add its columns, fill its cells and then give it as a datasource to your control 3) at rowdatabound event, get the cell's value's count of digit. if its bigger than 1, create a new row for every single digit and add them to your control.